# Xcode iphone simulator not running Retina?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I have added some graphic to my app, the size is directed to the Retina Display ress.

i have uncommented

```
// Enables High Res mode (Retina Display) on iPhone 4 and maintains low res on all other devices
if( ! [director enableRetinaDisplay:YES] )
    CCLOG(@"Retina Display Not supported");
```

but when i run my program i get "Retina Display Not supported", and i'm using the iPhone 4.3 emulator

What can i do to run Retina display, so that i can test my graphic.

Thx

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The Simulator (it's a simulator and not an emulator by the way) has a menu item to switch between retina and non-retina display: Hardware -> Device -> iPhone (Retina)

Comment: Thx Ole, the problem was i was looking inside xcodes menu! Thx again.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the full instruction below:

http://gensanblog.com/2012/11/16/how-to-activate-retina-mode-in-xcode-ios-simulator/

Comment: Could you provide a short description of the solution of the problem so your answer won't get lost if the link goes down?